# ViewPager with different adapters for portrait and landscape

Tags: android, android-viewpager, orientation-changes, fragmentstatepageradapter

In portrait mode, my `ViewPager` has 3 fragments A, B, C but in landscape mode, it has only 2 fragments A and C. So I create 2 `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`s for each mode. The problem is when screen orientation changed, `ViewPager` restores and uses previous fragments of old orientation. For example, when change orientation from portrait to landscape, `ViewPager` now shows 2 fragments A, B instead of A and C. I know why this happen but can't find a good solution for this.

My current workaround is to use different ids for `ViewPager` (eg: id/viewpager_portrait for portrait and id/viewpager_landscape for landscape layout) to prevent from reusing fragments but this cause me a memory leak because old fragment will not be destroyed and still be kept in memory.

I have tried some workaround like call super.onCreate(null) in activity's `onCreate`, or remove fragments of `ViewPager` in  activity's `onSaveInstanceState` but they all makes my app crash.

So my question is how to avoid reusing one or many fragments in `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` when orientation changed?

Any helps will be appreciated. Thank in advance.

Comment: Did you try overriding `onSaveInstanceState` and avoid calling `super.onSaveInstanceState` in that method. This would prevent the `Fragment` from getting saved.

Comment: That is my current workaround, but instead avoid calling super.onSaveInstanceState, I clear all state made by ViewPager. And I don't think this a the best solution so I still ask because sometime a see a crash from inside ViewPager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue probably is that the built-in `PagerAdapter` implementations for `Fragment`s provided by Android assume that the items will remain constant, and so retain and reuse index-based references to all `Fragment`s that are added to the `ViewPager`. These references are maintained through the `FragmentManager` even after the `Activity` (and `Fragment`s) is recreated due to configuration changes or the process being killed.

What you need to do is to write your own implementation of `PagerAdapter` that associates a custom tag with each `Fragment` and stores the `Fragment`s in a tag-based (instead of index-based) format. You could derive a generic implementation of this from one of the existing ones after adding an abstract method for providing a tag based on the index alongside the `getItem()` method. Of course, you will have to remove orphaned/unused `Fragment`s added in the previous configuration from the `ViewPager` (while ideally holding on to it's state).

If you don't want to implement the whole solution yourself, then the `ArrayPagerAdapter` in the [CWAC-Pager](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-pager) library can be used to provide a reasonable implementation of this with little effort. Upon initialization, you can detach the relevant `Fragment` based on it's provided tag, and remove/add it from the adapter as well, as appropriate.

Comment: I know that write my own adapter will solve problem but I think there is a better and easier solution than that so I ask on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Wayne: I have added some more information to the end of the answer, and also a suggestion to use the [CWAC-Pager](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-pager) library.

Comment: Thank you corsair992, my solution is to copy PagerAdapter source and change a bit of code base on your answer.
I'm sorry, I was not online last weekend so I forgot to give full bounty for you/

Answer (score 1):

Override `getItemPosition()` in your Adapter and return `POSITION_NONE`. So when the ViewPager is recreated it will call `getItemPosition()` and since you've returned `POSITION_NONE` from here, it will call `getItem()`. You should return the new fragments in from this `getItem()`. Ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getItemPosition%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: Oh I forgot about getItemPosition(). Maybe this will be a good solution. Thanks

Comment: This answer is not correct. `ViewPager` only looks for changes in item positions upon calls to `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `PagerAdapter`, and this would not work properly for removing an item from a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` anyway because it assumes the items to be immutable and it would mess up it's saved state associations. Not would it work for `FragmentPagerAdapter`, as it assumes the same thing, and will just reuse the original `Fragment`.

Answer (score 1):

Why use two different ids for your viewpager, when you can just remove Fragment B when your orientation changes?

You can retrieve your Fragments inside onCreateView() or onResume() like this (this example works inside a parent fragment, but is also usable inside a parent activity like in onResume() ):

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // ... initialize components, etc.

    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    List<Fragment> children = getChildFragmentManager().getFragments();

    if (children != null) {
        pagerAdapter.restoreFragments(children, orientation);
    }
}
```

Then inside your adapter:

```
@Override
public void restoreFragments(List<Fragment> fragments, int orientation) {
    List<Fragment> fragmentsToAdd = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    Collections.fill(fragmentsToAdd, null);
    if (Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE == orientation) {
        for (Fragment f : fragments) {
            if (!(f instanceof FragmentB)) {
                fragmentsToAdd.add(f);
            }
        }
    }
    this.fragmentsInAdapter = Arrays.copyOf(temp.toArray(new Fragment[0]), this.fragments.length); // array of all your fragments in your adapter (always refresh them, when config changes, else you have old references in your array!
    notifyDataSetChanged(); // notify, to remove FragmentB
}
```

That should work.

Btw. if you're using Support Library V13, you can't use FragmentManager.getFragments(), thus you'll need to get them by id or tag.

Answer (score 1):

Override OnConfigurationChanged() in your Activity (also add android:configChanges="orientation" to your activity in Manifest) this way you manage manually the the orientation change. Now "all" you have to do is to change the adapter in OnOrientaionChanged (also keep track of the current position). This way you use a single layout, a single ViewPager, and you don't have to worry about the fragment not getting recycled (well, you'll have plenty of work to make up for that).
Good luck!